# How can I achieve this without Case Statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, case

is there any alternative to case statement I want achieve below

*select
case when Etype=1 then 'Earthquake'
else 'Normal'
end
as Etype

Comment: I think it is not clear enough what you asking

Comment: I want replace 1 with Earthquake and 2 with Other in a variable(Column) without using case statement, I'm able to achieve this using SQL Case Statement

Comment: Create a lookup table for Etype (Something like EtypeMaster) which has an Id and Name columns. Id will be 1 and 2, and Name will be 'Earthquake' and 'Normal'. Now, join your current query with this table on the Id column, and select the Name column as output.

Comment: Please explain why you want to do this. It doesn't make any sense at all. Like saying "I want to add two numbers without using the + sign"?

Answer (score 0):

something like this will do, although not sure what's the benefit of not using case:

```
select substring('EarthquakeNormal',power(sign(Etype-1),2)*11,11)
```

I'm assuming Etype is always >=0 if is >0 then the power is not required.

Also, please note that this solution is for SQL Server 2008 but from SQL Server 2012 onward there are at least another 3 better ways of doing it. IIF , choose and even parsename.